# What is the equivalent of MATLAB's corrplot() or R's pairs() in Octave?

Tags: r, matlab, octave, correlation

R's **pairs()** displays the correlations between pairs of variables, here a graph example:[image: R's pairs() example]

What is the equivalent of it in Octave ?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain the reasons you downvoted the question so that the author won't repeat it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would seem to be `plotmatrix`:

```
plotmatrix (randn (100, 3), "g+")
```

[image]

Took me about two minutes via the Octave docs. You're welcome.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer! I have actually been searching for stuff like "octave plot correlations between variables", "r pairs octave equivalent" and so on...probably I might not be looking for the correct thing :S Thanks again for you help.